# Why wasn't PyPy included in standard Python?

Tags: python, pypy

I was looking at [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) and I was just wondering why it hasn't been adopted into the mainline Python distributions. Wouldn't things like JIT compilation and lower memory footprint greatly improve the speeds of all Python code?

In short, what are the main drawbacks of PyPy that cause it to remain a separate project?

Comment: In addition, pypy have no support for numpy, yet. http://morepypy.blogspot.ch/2012/09/numpy-on-pypy-status-update.html

Comment: And numpy support only scratches the surface of what scientific computing applications would need before switching to PyPy.  Here are some cogent thoughts from the original numpy author: http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2011/10/thoughts-on-porting-numpy-to-pypy.html

Comment: I think these answers and comments are outdated

Answer (score 255, accepted):

PyPy is not a fork of CPython, so it could never be merged directly into CPython.

Theoretically the Python community could universally adopt PyPy, PyPy could be made the reference implementation, and CPython could be discontinued. However, PyPy has its own weaknesses:

- CPython is easy to integrate with Python modules written in C, which is traditionally the way Python applications have handled CPU-intensive tasks (see for instance the SciPy project).
- The PyPy JIT compilation step itself costs CPU time -- it's only through repeated running of compiled code that it becomes faster overall.  This means startup times can be higher, and therefore PyPy isn't necessarily as efficient for running glue code or trivial scripts.
- PyPy and CPython behavior is not identical in all respects, especially when it comes to "implementation details" (behavior that is not specified by the language but is still important at a practical level).
- CPython runs on more architectures than PyPy and has been successfully adapted to run in embedded architectures in ways that may be impractical for PyPy.
- CPython's reference counting scheme for memory management arguably has more predictable performance impacts than PyPy's various GC systems, although this isn't necessarily true of all "pure GC" strategies.
- PyPy does not yet fully support Python 3.x, although that is an active work item.

PyPy is a great project, but runtime speed on CPU-intensive tasks isn't everything, and in many applications it's the least of many concerns.  For instance, Django can run on PyPy and that makes templating faster, but CPython's database drivers are faster than PyPy's; in the end, which implementation is more efficient depends on where the bottleneck in a given application is.

Another example: you'd think PyPy would be great for games, but most GC strategies like those used in PyPy cause noticeable jitter.  For CPython, most of the CPU-intensive game stuff is offloaded to the PyGame library, which PyPy can't take advantage of since PyGame is primarily implemented as a C extension (though see: pygame-cffi).  I still think PyPy can be a great platform for games, but I've never seen it actually used.

PyPy and CPython have radically different approaches to fundamental design questions and make different tradeoffs, so neither one is "better" than the other in every case.

Comment: It is not true that PyPy is unsuitable for running scripts. Its startup time is pretty much the same as CPython and its interpretation speed is similar.

Comment: It is worth noting that PyPy now comes with an incremental GC, and is potentially more suitable for games as a consequence.

Answer (score 63):

For one, it's [not 100% compatible](http://pypy.org/compat.html) with Python 2.x, and has only [preliminary support](http://pypy.org/py3donate.html) for 3.x.

It's also not something that could be merged - The Python implementation that is provided by PyPy is generated using a framework they have created, which is extremely cool, but also completely disparate with the existing CPython implementation. It would have to be a complete replacement.

There are some [very concrete differences](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html) between PyPy and CPython, a big one being how [extension modules](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#do-cpython-extension-modules-work-with-pypy) are supported - which, if you want to go beyond the standard library, is a big deal.

It's also worth noting that PyPy isn't universally faster.

Answer (score 57):

See [this video by Guido van Rossum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBRMq2Ioxsc#t=12m30s). He talks about the same question you asked at 12 min 33 secs.

Highlights:

- lack of Python 3 compatibility
- lack of extension support
- not appropriate as glue code
- speed is not everything

After all, he's the one to decide...

Comment: +1 for link WITH direct link to relevant part of video! Also +1 for hilariously truthful Guido van Rossum informal poll "how Many people are using PyPy in production?... no hands? *coughs* Well, I guess there is still hope [for CPython]."

Comment: FYI, the pypy topic ends in 18:35 (~ 6mins long) of the video, short enough for watching :).

Answer (score 15):

One reason might be that according to [PyPy](http://pypy.org/features.html) site, it currently runs only on 32- and 64-bit Intel x86 architecture, while CPython runs on other platforms as well. This is probably due to platform-specific speed enhancements in PyPy. While speed is a good thing, people often want language implementations to be as "platform-independent" as possible.

Comment: Note that an ARM backend is "almost there" and a [PowerPC backend](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/changesets/tip/branch%28%27ppc-jit-backend%27%29) is WIP. Also note that this only refers to the JIT compiler, and porting the JIT to a new architecture merely requires implementing a code generator for a relatively simple and low-level IR, nothing more.

Comment: As of 2018, PyPy now runs on [more architectures](https://morepypy.blogspot.fr/2018/01/pypy-5101-bugfix-release-for-python-35.html) x86 (32/64 bits on Linunx, Windows, MacOS and BSDs), but also, on Linux, newer ARM hardware (ARMv6 or ARMv7, with VFPv3), big- and little-endian variants of PPC64, and s390x.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend watching this keynote by [David Beazley](http://pyvideo.org/video/659/keynote-david-beazley) for more insights. It answers your question by giving clarity on nature & intricacies of PyPy.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to everything that's been said here, PyPy is not nearly as rock solid as CPython in terms of bugs.  With SymPy, we've found at about a dozen bugs in PyPy over the past couple of years, both in released versions and in the nightlies.

On the other hand, we've only ever found one bug in CPython, and that was in a prerelease.

Plus, don't discount the lack of Python 3 support. No one in the core Python community even cares about Python 2 any more. They are working on the next big things in Python 3.4, which will be the fifth major release of Python 3.  The PyPy guys still haven't gotten one of them. So they've got some catching up to do before they can start to be contenders.

Don't get me wrong. PyPy is awesome. But it's still far from being better than CPython in a lot of very important ways.

And by the way, if you use SymPy in PyPy, you won't see a smaller memory footprint (or a speedup either). See https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/1447/.

Comment: As of 2018, I can confirm that I have seen speedups of roughly an order of magnitude in different sympy uses

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans interesting. I'll have to try benchmarking it again.